# How to add bootstrap control to asp controls in master page so that it reflect to all of my asp:textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I want to set CssClass="form-control" to every textbox in my master page
So what should I do?

Comment: How about setting the `CssClass` of every textbox to `form-control`?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched for? Your question should provide more detail to get a good answer. I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but it seems like there should be some way to create a template or reuse HTML code but that might not be flexible enough if you have lots of different inputs. It wouldn't be too bad to set that class on each input. It would be hard to combine some default class with any extra classes you add to an individual input. Also if some global config is adding classes, it makes it harder to figure out later how classes are being applied to your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

In master page code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
//added next line
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710337/add-class-into-html-tag-by-jquery-in-asp-net-c-sharp
            //https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25280443/How-to-iterate-through-all-controls-with-masterpage.html
            var x = new object();
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control masterControl in Page.Controls)
                {
                    if (masterControl is MasterPage)
                    {
                        foreach (Control formControl in masterControl.Controls)
                        {
                            if (formControl is HtmlForm)
                            {

                                foreach (Control cont in formControl.Controls)
                                {
                                    if (cont is TextBox)
                                    {
                                        ((TextBox)cont).Attributes["class"] = "form-control";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In aspx of master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox1" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox2" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox3" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox4" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add CssClass on your control, that's it:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Make sure your bootstrap has reference on your Master Page style, under the Head section:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <%--Added Bootstrap Style Here--%>
    <link href="~/Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</style>
```